# OpenCV processed images are not getting displayed on HTML with base64 encoding

Tags: python, opencv, redis, base64, tornado

I have an example scenario. I am capturing some webcam images with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. I am then converting each frame to bytes and sending them to Redis db.

```
image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cap)
value = np.array(image).tobytes()
store.set('image', value)
```

From Redis, I am reconstructing the bytes back to images and then back to numpy array.

```
self._video_capture = self._store.get('image')
self.nparr = np.frombuffer(self._video_capture, np.uint8) # convert image into numpy array
self.img_np = cv2.imdecode(self.nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

I am then sending them back with a byte stream using Tornado(websocket) to be displayed on a HTML page.

```
image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', self.frame)
value = np.array(image).tobytes()
value = base64.b64encode(value)
self.write_message(value) #Websocket write function
```

The HTML page is reading the data as

```
data:image/jpg;base64
```

However the HTML page is not recognizing the base64 image data. The 'src' is displaying 16x16. What is possibly going wrong here?

Edit: The base64 encoded image data is in the form of `/<string>` instead of `/<string>/<string>/<string>/<string>/`

Comment: As I know,numpy use function `tobytes`,with the means "Construct Python bytes containing the raw data bytes in the array." may not means to a `jpg` picture data. when numpy open a jpg picture,it just get the NxMx3 matrix,not remember the file types.

Comment: If you are delivering content to IMG's SRC-attribute then don't you need to prepend the encoded values with the string "data:image/jpeg;base64," before write_message?